# On iOS, why does the following UITapGestureRecognizer (Tap) not work?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

If I just start a brand new Single View App project on Xcode 4.3.2, and use the following code:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] 
                              initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.jpg"]];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                               initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}

-(void) handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *) gesture {
    NSLog(@"Image tapped on");
}
```

The `handleTap` method is never called even if I tap on the image... is something not done correctly here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable touches in your image view (as it is disabled by default), not in controller's view:

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: by default userInteractionEnabled is true for parent but not for child

Comment: @Vladimir perfect answer!  have you been doing iOS / Cocoa programming for a long long time?!

Comment: @safecase, it is true for UIView class, but false for some subclasses, i.e. UILabel, UIImageView - you need to set it to YES explicitely

Answer (score 0):

Is `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` at the end of your @interface in your header file?